# How to manually delete a node from the database knowing its id

Tags: 7, nodes, database, entities

Well, look my problem is weird, I have a view that lists content of a desired type, it is listing all the content of a type, I have deleted from the drupal admin UI a node of that type, but the view is still listing the node I have deleted. If I try to access to that node from the view, I get an entityMetadataWrapperException

Now I cannot see the node in the drupal content admin UI.

I know the nid of this node (its 22) I need to delete it manually from the database, how to achieve this, is necesary a custom module or something?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try clearing the cache

Comment: no that is not the solution, I have this problem like a week ago, and clear cache neither run cron worked

Comment: I do not understand under what circumstances can a node be available in Views output even after getting deleted through admin UI. Only way i think its possible is if the output is coming from the views cache table. But you are saying clearing cache didn't help.

Comment: Have you done any manual SQL updates / deletes?  If so, you may have an inconsistent database and a entity reference, etc, field that points to the deleted node that didn't get cleaned up properly.

Comment: No I just did it through the UI, but I think the problem is that my hosting had a low php_memory_limit maybe that has something to do with this issue, however Im sure the node still exists due to I can list the node using id filtering in a vew, I did the test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`node_delete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7):

```
<?php
$nid='22'; // $node id , which you want to delete;
node_delete($nid);
?>
```

This function from the API does the necessary cleaning up when a node is deleted.

You can stick this in a custom module, or enable the [PHP filter](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php) and just have it a node where you allow PHP code.

If you use the PHP Filter method, remember to disable it when done.  You don't want it permanently enabled on a production site.

You may also want to repair your database, just to make sure.  The screenshot below shows how to use phpMyAdmin to repair the `{sessions}` table.  You can also use to repair the `{node}` table

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this is the right answer, I just created a module that implements hook_cron and in the next run cron I could delete the node and now the view is not listing this node. Thanks =)

Comment: It doesn't look like this works if the node to be deleted contains something that crashes the server. I don't know what it is exactly that I'm dealing with because when I try to view the node I get server error 500. I need to delete it because it's causing the Search index cron process to fail